# I am frequently getting this error - null is not an object (evaluating '_await$Location$getLa.coords') working with expo-location

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This is my code of custom hook from where i am returning the location of the device and asking the permission.This is a simple implementation but it is giving error

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const { granted } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (granted) {
        const { coords } = await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();
        const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
        setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

**I am using the function by importing it like this**
`import useLocation from "../hooks/useLocation";`
**And soring the value like this**
  `const location = useLocation()`
**It is giving error of null is not an object (evaluating '_await$Location$getLa.coords')**

Comment: If the granted variable is false the getLocation() return null. The problem might be on a other file in wich you are trying to use the getLocation() result as a null object. The error points to a function that does not appear in this code. Do you have an other file ?

Comment: @Gregoirelpv Yes I have another file from where i am calling the custom hook. I have ensured the granted var is true and location is on too.I have tried the same approach by directly using the `getlocation()`  function . But continuously it gives this error

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is related to the fact that the `getLastKnownPositionAsync()` function is returning null on some occasions.
This happens when the last position is not available or doesn't match certain requirements, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationgetlastknownpositionasyncoptions)

When this function is returning null, you can't destructure its result by using `const { coords } = await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();`.

Adding a null check should resolve the problem.

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const { granted } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (granted) {
        /* Change the code below this comment */
        const lastKnownPosition = await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync();
        if (!lastKnownPosition) {
            return;
        }
        const { latitude, longitude } = lastKnownPosition.coords;
        setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```